# CSRF prevention with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I use spring boot with spring security and hope to get default support of spring boot for csrf prevention.

I invoke a REST post api via postman with X-CSRF-TOKEN as header. But I get below error.

```
Invalid CSRF Token 'wJIJvkev' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

I try generate a token with UID and also with ESAPI, but still I get the error.  What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to _get_ the token from the server. You can't just generate an arbitrary some clientside. See [this tutorial](http://www.codesandnotes.be/2015/02/05/spring-securitys-csrf-protection-for-rest-services-the-client-side-and-the-server-side/) for an example of what needs to be done.

Comment: So I need to have a seperate rest end point to generate a token?

Comment: Yup. If you want CSRF on your REST endpoints, you need to get the token stored in the server session somehow. This is easier with browser based applications as you can write the token as part of the page on the server response, and use that for any subsequent request/Ajax. With REST I would suggest disabling CSRF unless you are using a "write" verb, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc.

Comment: If I disable CSRF, my application is vulnerable for CSRF attacks know? By the way, is it ok to use same csrf token for all subsequent request for any user?

Comment: CSRF requests only affect "write" type requests. As you know, an attacker cannot read the result of a request to a foreign domain; they attack "blind" - the the vulnerability arises when the sent `PUT` or `DELETE` type requests to resources. If you REST API is mutable, then yes - you will be vulnerable. As to the second part of the question; no, probably not; in a secure application the CSRF token is regularly rotated.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I would also like to know how to prevent Cross-Site-Scripting attack with spring boot+spring security. Can you provide some information on it pls?

Comment: Given the question and your comments, there seems to be no specific issue here; but more "how does spring work". As such, this question is not of a suitable format for this site.

Comment: I understand. I add a seperate question for it. Would you mind have a look pls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872967/cross-site-scripting-prevention-with-spring-security